# How do I get a slice from an array reference?

Tags: perl

Let us say that we have following array:

```
my @arr=('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr');
my @arr2=@arr[0..2];
```

How can we do the same thing if we have array reference like below:

```
my $arr_ref=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr'];
my $arr_ref2; # How can we do something similar to @arr[0..2]; using $arr_ref ?
```

Answer (score 40):

To get a slice starting with an array reference, replace the array name with a block containing the array reference. I've used whitespace to spread out the parts, but it's still the same thing:

```
 my @slice =   @   array   [1,3,2];
 my @slice =   @ { $aref } [1,3,2];
```

If the reference inside the block is a simple scalar (so, not an array or hash element or a lot of code), you can leave off the braces:

```
 my @slice =   @$aref[1,3,2];
```

Then, if you want a reference from that, you can use the anonymous array constructor:

```
 my $slice_ref = [ @$aref[1,3,2] ];
```

With the new [post-dereference feature (experimental) in v5.20](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/),

```
use v5.20;
use feature qw(postderef);
no warnings qw(experimental::postderef);

my @slice = $aref->@[1,3,2];
```

Comment: That post-dereference feature seems really useful!

Answer (score 13):

Just slice the reference (the syntax is similar to dereferencing it, see the comments), and then turn the resulting list back into a ref:

```
my $arr_ref2=[@$arr_ref[0..2]];
```

Comment: that's not what that does.  `@$ref[...]` is an array slice using a reference; there is no intermediate array generated.
See http://perlmonks.org?node=References+quick+reference

Comment: oh, maybe by "resulting array" you mean what's generated by the array slice?  That's not an array, it's a list.

Comment: @ysth: Surely it's not misleading to think of an array slice using reference as slicing the array which is the result of dereferencing the reference?

Comment: It's bad to make people think `@$ref[...]` is as inefficient as `(@$ref)[...]`

Comment: Remember the difference between a list an an array: http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/01/whats-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array/ :)

Answer (score 5):

```
my $arr_ref2 = [ @$arr_ref[0..2] ];
```